# Firebase real-time database: Impossible to extend the test-mode period

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I originally created a real-time database with the default test-mode 30 days period, then I started to receive emails stating that client access is expiring in N days.

So I updated my rules to use a date far in the future:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1767225599000",  // 2025-12-31
    ".write": "now < 1767225599000"  // 2025-12-31
  }
}
```

But I kept received these warning emails. Finally, I updated my rules as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

But I'm still receiving the warning emails. How can it be? Isn't it possible to extend the test-period?

**Updated:** I'm getting the following kind of mails

> [Firebase] Client access to your Realtime Database
> 'unibeam-demo-default-rtdb' is expiring in 1 day(s)
>
> You chose to
> start developing in Test Mode, which leaves your Realtime Database
> instance completely open to the Internet. Because this choice makes
> your app vulnerable to attackers, your database security rules were
> configured to stop allowing requests after the first 30 days.
>
> In 1 day(s), all client requests to your Realtime Database instance
> will be denied. Before that time, please update your security rules to
> allow your app to function while appropriately protecting your data.
> Analysis is run daily; if you've modified your rules in the last 24
> hours those changes may not be accounted for.

Comment: In those last rules you should only be getting alerts that your rules are insecure, not about that database access is about to expire. Are you sure the emails are for the exact project where you are changing the security rules?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated my question with the content of the last warning email I received. Yes, I'm sure it's for the same exact Firebase project (I only have one of them...)

Comment: How long ago did you change the rules? It may take up to 48 hours before the emails stop coming, as they're scheduled in advance.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I changed the rules less than 48 hours ago